# How to get middle div you fill vertical space?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am fairly new to web design and i'm trying to test out page layouts. I have a layout with a header, left floating div, right floating div, body, and footer. What i'm trying to do is to get the "body" div to fill the vertical space between the floating divs. And also, if possible, how could I get the entire layout to fill the vertical space of the screen? I included an image at the bottom of the page, i'm trying to fill in all the scribbled space.

Here is my html code,

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
}
header,
footer {
  background-color: rgb(000, 000, 000);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: left;
}
#nav {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#body {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#right {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
  float: right;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="nav">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, integer velit senectus sit, proin ut id nec eu vel aliquet, pellentesque et venenatis lacinia aliquet wisi, bibendum mauris, fames turpis. Lectus nibh gravida wisi pede vel. Eu feugiat ligula aliquam mi, dolor quis, sollicitudin
        ut, quis mauris magna lectus. Velit a dignissim et, phasellus convallis sed condimentum, cum vitae consequat laoreet vestibulum. Rhoncus felis porttitor vitae, est mi ac etiam et ligula est. Rhoncus egestas erat fringilla, praesent et augue ultricies
        aliquam. Nascetur imperdiet nisl porttitor aenean, ante ipsum ornare magni, arcu consectetur, a pulvinar.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, integer velit senectus sit, proin ut id nec eu vel aliquet, pellentesque et venenatis lacinia aliquet wisi, bibendum mauris, fames turpis. Lectus nibh gravida wisi pede vel. Eu feugiat ligula aliquam mi, dolor quis, sollicitudin
        ut, quis mauris magna lectus. Velit a dignissim et, phasellus convallis sed condimentum, cum vitae consequat laoreet vestibulum. Rhoncus felis porttitor vitae, est mi ac etiam et ligula est. Rhoncus egestas erat fringilla, praesent et augue ultricies
        aliquam. Nascetur imperdiet nisl porttitor aenean, ante ipsum ornare magni, arcu consectetur, a pulvinar.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, integer velit senectus sit, proin ut id nec eu vel aliquet, pellentesque et venenatis lacinia aliquet wisi, bibendum mauris, fames turpis. Lectus nibh gravida wisi pede vel. Eu feugiat ligula aliquam mi, dolor quis, sollicitudin
        ut, quis mauris magna lectus. Velit a dignissim et, phasellus convallis sed condimentum, cum vitae consequat laoreet vestibulum. Rhoncus felis porttitor vitae, est mi ac etiam et ligula est. Rhoncus egestas erat fringilla, praesent et augue ultricies
        aliquam. Nascetur imperdiet nisl porttitor aenean, ante ipsum ornare magni, arcu consectetur, a pulvinar.</p>
    </div>
    <footer>Bottom</footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[What i'm trying to figure out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxnqt.png)

Comment: its working fine only https://jsfiddle.net/xwsxupv0/ ... what exactly you want to do with :)

Comment: I would like the "body" div to entirely fill the space between the two floating divs.

Comment: You almost done :)

Comment: happy coding :) <3

Comment: This will be quite hard to do with floats. Especially if you have a height that can change. But it can be done with flexbox. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xwsxupv0/3/ If this is what you want I can add a more detailed explanation later. (just leave a comment if you want me to)

Comment: That worked well, thank you. I haven't used flex before, but I'm glad I know what it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
  div.container {
    width:100%;
    border:solid 1px;
  }
  header, footer {
    background-color:rgb(000,000,000);
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    clear:left;
  }
  #nav {
    background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.8);
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;
  }
  #body {
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.8);
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  #right {
    background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.8);
    float:right;
    max-width:150px;
    padding:10px;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwsxupv0/1/

Comment: if the `#body` will have more enough content - remove the `height:100vh` in css. And make the both floating divs `position:fixed`. Now you will get better design. ( fixed right and left , scrolling body div )